# CSS3 and JavaScript Print Area

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a code here which print outs the table in my html. Here is the code:

**CSS:**

```
  @media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  #reportArea, #reportArea * {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  #reportArea {
    right:0;
    padding:0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

}
```

html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success hidden-print" onclick="window.print();">

<div id="reportArea">
  <h3 class="text-center">Hotelier Reservation Summary Report</h3>
  &nbsp;&nbsp; Summary Report For: {{ $from }} - {{ $to }} 
  <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Room #</th>
          <th class="hidden-print">Invoice #</th>
          <th>Client Name</th>
          <th>Booked At</th>
          <th>Reservation From</th>
          <th>Reservation To</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
      </thead>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($reservations as $res)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $res -> room -> room_number }}</td>
          <td class="hidden-print">
            <a href="/payment/invoice?reservation_id={{ $res -> id }}">{{ date('Ymd').'-'.$res -> id }}</a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ $res -> client -> name }}</td>
          <td>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($res -> created_at )) }}</td>
          <td>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($res -> reservation_from)) }}</td>
          <td>{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($res -> reservation_to)) }}</td>
          <td>&#8369;{{ number_format($res -> charge -> sum('price'), 2) }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
          <td class="hidden-print"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><strong>&#8369;{{ number_format($total, 2) }}</strong></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I wanted to do is to occupy all the space in the paper. When I run this code, I get this one:

[image]

As you can see, there is a big space in the right part of the paper. How can I maximize the use of the paper? I mean ,extend the table more to the right so that it will fit the paper. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please rephrase for clarity. Is the image at the bottom when printed or is it how the site works by itself?

Comment: What do you mean? @AMACB

Comment: Never mind, i think my browser was being silly.

Comment: Updated the image @AMACB

Answer (score 1):

**Even invisible elements take up space on the page. Use the display property to create invisible elements that do not take up space!**

```
body * {
  display: none;
}

#reportArea, #reportArea * {
  display: auto;
}
```

Comment: Still the same output

Comment: then check how it looks like, without @media print and if the page filled out correctly, then it might be just your print settings

Comment: Does changing the `width: 100%;` to the table do anything? Otherwise, try using a different browser (I have known chrome to be funky with PDF handling)

Comment: width: 100% could also depend on the outer divs.. just remove the print, style it with the debugger and then test it with print again..